# Strange behavior validating IP address

Tags: powershell

Strange IP address after validation an IP address.
For example:

```
$ipnr = "010.010.010.100"
[System.Net.IPAddress]$ip = $ipnr
```

`$ipnr` returned 8.8.8.100.

Saw that an octet like `'07'` has no issues. it starts at `'08'`.
I have to validate because the string can have leading zeros.
Of course I can trim and remove leading zeros from the octets, but find it strange, the validate with `[IPAddress]` is not working.

Comment: What is that you feel strange? IP address having leading zeroes in the octets ?

Comment: that is because - if your _octet_ is shown as base 8, you will get base eight interpretation. [*grin*] `010` is ... _eight_ in base 8.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers with leading zeroes are interpreted as octal numbers (octal 010 == decimal 8). To fix the issue remove the leading zeroes, e.g. like this:

```
[Net.IPAddress]$ip = [int[]]$ipnr.Split('.') -join '.'
```

or like this:

```
[Net.IPAddress]$ip = $ipnr -replace '(?<=^|\.)0+'
```